# How to get the id of a edge from its two id vertex in C and Igraph?

Tags: c, igraph

How to get the id of a specific edge with two of its vertex?

Example:

egde id=4 with vertex 2 and 3, using id 2 and 3 vertex how to get the id=4 of that edge?

Comment: Please add some more details, and your code. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`igraph_get_eid`](http://igraph.sourceforge.net/doc/html/ch04s02s02.html#igraph_get_eid) is the function you are looking for.